# Increase the height of the legends in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How would I set the legend height so that it does not show the pagination below the legends?

[image]

code:

```
legend: {
       align: 'right',
       itemMarginBottom: 8,
       labelFormatter: function() {//some func},
        itemWidth: 290,
       verticalAlign: 'top',
       useHTML: true,
       x: 95,
       y:80
}
```

any ideas appreciated. Thanks!

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ag6j7f6w/

Comment: there is [maxHeight](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.maxHeight) to set height of legend

Comment: @Deep3015: tried that, still the pagination shows

Comment: any fiddle link to problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/23x2y70a/ see this

Comment: @Deep3015: its in extjs: https://jsfiddle.net/ag6j7f6w/ also tried the exporting option, not sure if that would be a correct way to do so though!

Comment: i cannot understand extjs .try to update the question  with extjs code and add tag  extjs to question. some one cloud help

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the issue - it is not complete. Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) To disbale pagination set legend.navigation.enabled to false http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend.navigation.enabled http://jsfiddle.net/23x2y70a/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the height & width of your chart.By doing so the pagination will not come up.
Increase the width: 600 & height: 650 of chart.